# How can we move a Craft-built website to a new web designer?

Tags: admin, license

We have a new website waiting to be published, and we would like to hire a new web design team, who is not a Craft Pro User...Is there anyway to get our website off of Craft or are we stuck with getting our own Pro Account? Please HELP!

Answer (score 3):

The Craft Pro accounts are per domain, not per user. If you want all the features of Craft Pro, you will need your own license. (http://buildwithcraft.com/pricing)

Comment: Thanks for posting...I guess I wasnt entirely clear. We would like to have a site that could be portable, off of the Craft platform at any given time. If we take ownership of our site,  will we lose the licensed code/html/java ect. that was built with Craft by our current designer? Thank you kindly.

Comment: @Rose - thanks for clarifying! Since the license is per domain, it should be transferred to you by the designer who built the site. The code developed by your current designer is not owned by Craft in any way, so you shouldn't lose any code. If you want to move away from the Craft platform, I imagine most of the site will have to be rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you! So basically, if we want to keep our site, the new designers will adapt to the Craft platform and we gain access to make the changes. I really appreciate your help, this is not a simple transition by any means.

Comment: Rose: Adding to what Aaron mention above, if your new designer wants to work with the site locally (on his computer), he can do so without problem. The only limiting factor is that he should run the site under a domain containing .dev. For example: flowershop.dev. You can also read more about transfering from one domain to another over at http://buildwithcraft.com/help/transferring-purchases

Answer (score 2):

[Aaron's answer is exactly right...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8687/45) the "Pro" status refers to the entire website, not an individual user.

If your old developer has restricted permissions of the other users, here's how you can regain access to the rest of the control panel:

1. Access the database directly (via phpMyAdmin, Sequel Pro, or a similar tool).
2. Find the `craft_users` table.
3. Find the user whom you would like to grant full access of the control panel.
4. Under the `admin` column, change the value to `1`.

That's it! That user will now have full super-admin access.

---

If you are still looking for a new Craft developer to hire, there are many talented folks out there. The two best places to find someone are:

- Post to the [Straight Up Craft - Jobs Board](http://straightupcraft.com/jobs)
- Tweet about your job opportunity with the hashtag of [#craftcms](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23craftcms)

Comment: Thanks for replying...I have no expereince with Craft, this is something that has surfaced after we have requested that our site be turned over to another design company, that our site was built off of Craft. Im wondering how we can transfer our site to another platform entirely, or if we are stuck...and will need to have a Pro License for our new designers to gain access...Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are ditching Craft in favor of another platform (ie: WordPress or similar), then you'll largely be starting over. You'll only need a Pro license if the site was **already built** with a Pro license... in which case, you've (theoretically) already got it. If you simply want to know **where your HTML is located**, then take a look in the `/craft/templates` folder.

Comment: Thats great information, thank you kindly!

Comment: On a slightly more biased / informed note: It seems you are in a bad situation where your current developer isn't working out. Incase you discover that the site doesn't function that well, and you feel that Craft as a platform isn't suited for you, don't despair: I promise you that there is nothing wrong with the platform - it's fantastic for managing content - the possible problem might be implementation. In that case, it's much better to contact one of the skilled professionals in the Craft community.